# Gaussian integral where the integration limit is a linear function of a lower dimensional vector

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, probability-distributions

I want to compute
$$
f(x) = \int\nolimits_{-\infty}^{\Lambda x} \phi_q(y; \mu, \Sigma)\ dy
$$
where $p \ll q$, $x \in \mathcal{R}^p$, $\Lambda \in \mathcal{R}^{q \times p}$, $\mu \in \mathcal{R}^q$, $\Sigma \in \mathcal{R}^{q \times q}$ is positive-definite, $\operatorname{rank}(\Lambda) = p$,
and $\phi_q(y; \mu, \Sigma)$
is the pdf of the $q$-dimensional normal distribution with parameters $\mu, \Sigma$.

Is there a way to represent $f(x)$ in a way that allows it to be computed or approximated more efficiently than to compute a $q$-dimensional Gaussian CDF? How about if $\mu = 0$?

More generally, what are the sorts of tools used to attack problems like this?

Comment: $\Lambda x$ seems to be in $\mathcal{R}^q$, so does the lower limit of integration mean $-\infty$ in each component?

Comment: @robjohn: Yes. Is there a clearer way to indicate that?

Comment: If $\Lambda x=\mu$ and if $\Sigma$ is diagonal, the answer is $1/2^q$. Apart from that...